# How to avoid popup in http request

Tags: apache, http, url, url-routing

I have a url. when i access this through browser a popup comes and ask for user name and password and by giving right credential it opens the page. I want to know how to avoid the popup by passing the user name and password url itself and how to do that

note my username contains *@* symbol

Thanks A Lot

Comment: can u please elaborate ?? or paste some code ..with this less info ..very  difficult to answer  the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form:

```
http://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/<path>
```

It even works with @ in the username (IE might not support this).